# Extract password of a 7Z file from pcap

Tags: wireshark

I was able to apply a "ftp-data" filter on a pcap file and was able to extract the contents of a `abc.7z` file. It is a password protected file and needs a password to open it. Is there a way to find the password hidden inside a pcap file that has captured FTP traffic? I tried to filter with "http" and followed HTTP and TCP streams, but there isn't any useful information there.

Comment: probably not, there's no reason the zip's password would be sent through FTP. The client downloads the zip from the FTP, then input the password locally on his machine.

Comment: That said if that's an exercise, I would look into other text files downloaded from the FTP hoping one of them contains the password of the .7z file.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron is correct.

If somebody were to send a password-protected file *and* the password over the same network, and did not send the password in some encrypted form (TLS connection, SSH session, protected Wi-Fi network, etc.), then somebody sniffing the network would be able to do exactly what you're trying to do, i.e. access the file's contents.

So, unless the password was sent in that fashion by a user who didn't know that it exposed the password, and thus the file, to sniffers or who didn't care that it exposed the password, and thus the file, to sniffers, you won't have access to the password from a network capture.